# How do i specify a formula field in task to display mobile

Tags: formula, configuration

I want to show a mobile on the tasks. So i thought of creating a formula field on tasks, But i am not sure on how do i set the formula as the task could be related to a contact or lead.

How do i set it based on the WhoId so if a lead is selected then the mob of the lead is displayed or if a contact is selected then the mobile of contact is displayed?

Comment: Is mobile your custom field ?

Comment: yes.. its a custom field

Comment: Since its a custom field you can create a formula field that picks value from your custom field and it will pick up the value directly from the task object inspite of contact or lead.Also i assume that Mobile your custom field is on Task.

Comment: If you have a field on contact or lead you can go for a trigger.After Winter 13 release we can get the sObject based on Id.

Comment: "Mutant fields" like WhoId (or in many cases even record's `OwnerId` which can point to User or Queue) don't work nicely with formulas. Salesforce will let you use only fields that surely exist on all possible lookup targets - pretty much only `Id` and `Name`. So some coding solution will be needed - either trigger as @MohithKumar suggests or some field prepopulation in the new Task's URL...

Comment: Thanks guys.. I was aware of the trigger but thought if there was a way to set it up using formula, it would be great. But since its not there we need to use the trigger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot reference polymorphic lookup fields (WhoId & WhatId) in a formula because they could be pointing to one of many possible entities.

You will need a before insert, before update trigger to query for those WhoIds, query for the Mobile and then set it.

```
Trigger TaskBefore on Task(before insert, before update){
    Map<Id, List<Task>> whoIds = new Map<Id, List<Task>>{};

    For (Task t : trigger.new)
        If(t.WhoId != null){
            List<Task> tasks = whoIds.get(t.WhoId); //this should be t.WhoId (not task.WhoId)
            If (tasks == null){
            tasks = new List<Task>{};
            whoIds.put(t.WhoId, tasks);
        }
        tasks.add(t);
    }

    For (Lead ld : [Select Id, Name, Mobile from lead where Id in :whoIDs.keySet()])
        For(Task t : whoIds.get(ld.id))
            t.Mobile__c = ld.Mobile;

    For(Contact con : [Select Id, Name, Mobile from Contact where Id in :whoIds.keySet()])
        For(Task t : whoIds.get(con.id))
            t.Mobile__c = con.Mobile;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a field on contact or lead you can go for a trigger.After Winter 13 release we can get the sObject based on Id.

Here is an example

```
Id accid=[Select Id  from Account Limit 1].ID;
Schema.Sobjecttype inspecttype=accid.getSObjectType();
system.debug('Object Token '+inspecttype);
```

From the whoId of Task  you can determine the sObject Type and then from the sObject you can pull the custom field value and populate on new field on task.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer above works when Task is created or Updated BUT suppose a Task created/updated 3 days ago and today someone change the field value on Contact. The new value will not be populated on Task. It will hold wrong information. So I think, to replicate formula field functionality, a trigger on Contact will also be required.

Or another workaround is to create a Contact lookup field on Task and populate it with WhoId if WhoId is related to Contact. Then you can create a formula field on this new  Contact lookup field.