# Trigger to get fields from Object linked with the 'Related To' field in an Task

Tags: apex

This is linked to this other Salesforce Stack Exchange question and answer: [Trigger to get fields from Object linked with the 'Related To' field in an Event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21612/trigger-to-get-fields-from-object-linked-with-the-related-to-field-in-an-event)

I have a custom object called Customer_Statement__c. When I associate a task to a record of this sObject, a custom lookup (account) field on the task called 'Account_Name__c' should be populated with the Account__c value on the Customer_Statement__c field.

There is no compile error but when I create a task and have the task.type as 'Customer_Statement__c', the following error message is returned:

'**execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.AccountFromCustomerStatementOnTask: line 9, column 1**'

I am confused about this error because the trigger puts the what.id in the Map as per line 7.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

```
trigger AccountFromCustomerStatementOnTask on Task (after insert, after update, before insert, before update) { 

    Map<Id, List<Task>> taskWhatIds = new Map<Id, List<Task>>{};

        for (Task t : trigger.new) {
            if (t.What.Type == 'Customer_Statement__c') {
                taskWhatIds.put(t.whatId, new List<Task>()); 
            }
                taskWhatIds.get(t.WhatId).add(t);
    }


    for (Customer_Statement__c cs: [Select Id, Account__c FROM Customer_Statement__c WHERE Id IN :taskWhatIds.keySet()]){
        for (task t : taskWhatIds.get(cs.id)){
            t.Account_Name__c = cs.Account__c;
        }
    }
}
```

**TL;DR** Objects in triggers can only get values from fields which are on the actual object itself. So I replaced t.what.type == 'abc' with String.valueOf(t.WhatId).startsWith('a00')) { //. This string method checks if the first 3 chars of the record Id correspond to the custom object id. More info here: [What are Salesforce ID's composed of?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern for doing what I think you want is this:

```
        if (t.What.Type == 'Customer_Statement__c') {
            List<Task> tasks = taskWhatIds.get(t.WhatId);
            if (tasks == null) {
                tasks = new List<Task>();
                taskWhatIds.put(t.WhatId, tasks);
            }
            tasks.add(t); 
        }
```

where if there is already a list present in the map it is used else a list is added to the map. Then the object is added to the list. All of this has to be inside the `if` block.

**PS** But see Fernando's important point.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: whenever you create a task where What type is different from Customer_Statement__c it'll fail in the same way.

Objects in a trigger only contain the values on the object fields. For values on related objects (i.e. What.Type), you'll have to query using either a `SELECT` statement ou a `database.query`.

p.s.: don't forget to bulkify your code to avoid unnecessary queries.

Comment: Ah - very helpful. In the end I went with for (Task t : trigger.new) { if (String.valueOf(t.WhatId).startsWith('a00')) { // logic. Is there any better way you could think on how to achieve this, since as per this link - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of - not all unique ids (the first three characters in an id) are actually unique. Thanks!