# how to fetch contact custom fields from task object

Tags: soql

I have below query fetching contact fields and task fields from task object

```
SELECT Id,Who.Name, Subject,Description, ActivityDate, Status, OwnerId, CreatedBy.Name, 
                         CreatedDate,LastModifiedById FROM Task
```

but when I change who.name to any who.CustomFieldFromContact__c object, I get an error

**CustomFieldFromContact__c is a date field**

can someone please suggest how to fetch custom contact fields from task object?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't any way to do this.

The `Who` field is a polymorphic relationship that can point to either a Contact or User.  Because of this, traversing the relationship via the dot notation isn't currently possible.

Similar questions with similar answers:
[How do i specify a formula field in task to display mobile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4334/how-do-i-specify-a-formula-field-in-task-to-display-mobile)

Essentially you'll need to query your tasks, create a list of who ids, then separately query the Contact table and join them together in your own code.

Comment: Isn't the `Who`, a Lead or a Contact? In contract to a User or Contact?