# How to populate a text field on Task with the WhoID/'Name' Owner?

Tags: process-builder, formula, tasks, activities

How do I adapt my Task Process Builder to reach into the WhoID (aka the 'Name' field) on the Task in order to populate a text field on the Task with the WhoID *Owner's* name.

In other words, if the WhoID/Name on a Task is a kid, and the record owner for that kid is a social worker, how do I display that social worker's name on the Task record? (for anyone curious, 'Assigned To' is a Queue, and we need to see the ultimately responsible individual's name on the record too).

I don't have the option on Task to drill into WhoID/'Name' for related field values and I'm guessing this is one of those limitations of the Task/Activity object. I'm not a developer and I don't know code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i specify a formula field in task to display mobile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4334/how-do-i-specify-a-formula-field-in-task-to-display-mobile).

Comment: It does, thank you! It seems that it is not possible to do what I want to do declaratively.